# Using Nutch on window

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am facing some problem in crawl with Nutch. I followed the tutorial from [here](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) but with error:

```
" /home/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt -crawlId TestCrawl
Failed with exit value 1.
"
```

Can anyone provide a guideline for me to reference how to use nutch correctly on window?

Answer (score 0):

I have failed multiple times trying to set up Apache Nutch with either Hbase or MongoDB independently due to version clashes and weak online references. I would rather suggest using any DockerFile to help guide you through a set up. You may either use Docker to load an image or if you want Nutch locally setup, just follow all commands in any working DockerFile. Here is an [example](https://github.com/smartive/docker-nutch-elasticsearch-mongodb/tree/master/nutch) of such a DockerFile that you may use to get started.

After a successful setup, you can crawl using:

```
[NUTCH_DIRECTORY]/bin/crawl -i -s seed.txt crawldata <NUM_ROUNDS>
```

This will perform the complete crawl process(inject, fetch, parse and generate).

You may then view parsed content by running this command:

```
./nutch readlinkdb data/linkdb/ -dump out
cat out/part-00000
```

Hope this helps!